# how can i get sum of all the qty from nested array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, jsx

I want to get sum of the `qty` values from the data. I tried, but I am only getting the total qty for the first item in the array.

I just want the result `10` from below (4 + 5 + 0 + 1)

```js
let xyz = [{
    catid: '1',
    catName: 'abc',
    product: [{
        id: 1,
        qty: 4,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        qty: 5,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    catid: '2',
    catName: 'efg',
    product: [{
        id: 3,
        qty: 0,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        qty: 1,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lodash fp** if you don't mind

```js
const xyz = [ {catid: "1", catName: "abc", product: [{ id: 1, qty: 4 }, { id: 2, qty: 5 }]},{ catid: "2", catName: "efg", product: [{ id: 3, qty: 0 },{ id: 4, qty: 1 }]}];

const result = _(xyz).flatMap('product').sumBy('qty');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To do what you require you can use `reduce()`. You will need to nest two `reduce()` calls, one to sum the inner `qty` for each product, then another to sum the total for all products:

```js
let xyz = [ {catid: "1", catName: "abc", product: [{ id: 1, qty: 4 }, { id: 2, qty: 5 }]},{ catid: "2", catName: "efg", product: [{ id: 3, qty: 0 },{ id: 4, qty: 1 }]}];

var total = xyz.reduce((t0, o) => t0 + o.product.reduce((t1, prod) => t1 + prod.qty, 0), 0);
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Uglier way with 2 forEach..

```js
let xyz = [{
    catid: '1',
    catName: 'abc',
    product: [{
        id: 1,
        qty: 4,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        qty: 5,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    catid: '2',
    catName: 'efg',
    product: [{
        id: 3,
        qty: 0,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        qty: 1,
      }
    ]
  }
]

let sum = 0;

xyz.forEach(element => {
  element.product.forEach(product => {
    sum += product['qty'];
  });
});

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let totalqTy = 0;
xyz.forEach(o => {
  totalqTy += o.product.map(p => p.qty).reduce(((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested loop. [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) will do the trick.

```js
let xyz = [{
    catid: '1',
    catName: 'abc',
    product: [{
        id: 1,
        qty: 4,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        qty: 5,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    catid: '2',
    catName: 'efg',
    product: [{
        id: 3,
        qty: 0,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        qty: 1,
      }
    ]
  }
]

const quantity = (input) =>
    input.reduce((p, { product }) => 
        p + product.reduce((p, { qty }) => p + qty, 0), 0)

console.log(quantity(xyz)) // 10
```